# Filtering data loaded into Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have raw data stored in S3 as parquet.
I want a subset of that data loaded into Redshift.
To be clear, the Redshift data would be the result of a query (joins, filters, aggregations) of the raw data.

I originally thought that I could build views in Athena, and load the results into Redshift - but seems that it's not that simple !

Glue ETL jobs need an S3 or RDS source - will not accept a view from Athena.
(Cannot crawl a view either).

Next solution, was to have a play with the Athena CTAS functionality, write the results of the view to S3, and then load into RedShift.
However, there is no 'overwrite' option with CTAS.

So questions ...
Is there an easier way to approach this ? (seems a simple requirement)
Is there an easy workaround to execute a CTAS with 'overwrite' behaviour ?
With that, would have to be a solution that could be bundled up into a scheduled job - and already I think is leading into a custom script.

When a simple job becomes so difficult - I cannot help but think I'm missing something simple !?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ol' reliable: use a lambda! Lambda functions can programmatically connect to both s3 and redshift to execute SQL statements, and you have many options for what will trigger the lambda (if it's just a one-time thing, you can just have it be a scheduled lambda). You will be able use cloudwatch logs to examine the process too.

But beware: I noticed that you stored your data as a parquet... Normal Redshift does not support parquet formatted data. So, if you want to store types like structs, etc. you will need to use Redshift Spectrum.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go see if I can get that together - my first lambda !  Will report back.

Comment: I've finally managed to get this working. It seems quite convoluted -  Dropping existing CTAS table & associated S3 files, call SQL to create new CTAS so that the results go to S3, then Truncate and copy S3 to Redshift.  At the same time, the lambda is running all the time that the CTAS and Redshift Copy is running - so unnecessary cost. Still, it works ! Am sure I will look for more streamlined and simple solutions, but  for now this fills the basic brief so thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Seems like you may have a superfluous step in there... from the way you describe it in your question, it seems like the flow should be as follows: create a connection with your s3 bucket and redshift, query s3 bucket to get condensed data, then loop through the resultset and insert them into Redshift. But I may have misinterpreted your question. Also Lambda's are stupidly cheap... excepting a few cases where runtime/memory is especially small/large.

Comment: The shortened flow you describe would work, but for maintenance and organization perspective, not keen on having the query logic hidden away in code in the lambda - especially when dozens or hundreds of views.